# Como juntar valores repetidos de um array de objetos, somente em um objeto desse mesmo array?

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho a seguinte saída:

```js
[ { rank: 1, item: { userName: 'Rafaela', score: 600 } },
  { rank: 2, item: { userName: 'Carla', score: 410 } },
  { rank: 2, item: { userName: 'Yuri', score: 410 } },
  { rank: 3, item: { userName: 'Jompas', score: 300 } },
  { rank: 4, item: { userName: 'Jonas', score: 266 } },
  { rank: 4, item: { userName: 'Tereza', score: 266 } },]
```

Os empates do rank são exibidos um abaixo do outro com a mesma colocação.
gostaria de saber uma maneira de pegar esses empates e salvar dentro de um objeto só, para receber a seguinte saída:

```js
[ 
    { rank: 1, item: { userName: ['Rafaela'], score: 600 }},
    { rank: 2, item: { userName: ['Carla', 'Yuri'], score: 410 }},
    { rank: 3, item: { userName: ['Jompas'], score: 300 } },
    { rank: 4, item: { userName: ['Jonas, Tereza'], score: 266 } },]
```

gostaria de receber os dados assim ou de maneira semelhante.
Já tentei de varias maneira mas o código ficou grande e não deu muito certo, acredito que aja alguma forma mais simples de resolver.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode colocar os ranks em um set para remover as duplicidades, convertê-lo em um array e usar a função map para gerar o resultado no formato que você precisa de maneira bem elegante e breve.

```js
let data = [ 
  { rank: 1, item: { userName: 'Rafaela', score: 600 } },
  { rank: 2, item: { userName: 'Carla', score: 410 } },
  { rank: 2, item: { userName: 'Yuri', score: 410 } },
  { rank: 3, item: { userName: 'Jompas', score: 300 } },
  { rank: 4, item: { userName: 'Jonas', score: 266 } },
  { rank: 4, item: { userName: 'Tereza', score: 266 } }]

let result = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.rank))].map( x => {
    return{
        rank: x,
        item : {
            userName : data.filter(d => d.rank == x).map( u => u.item.userName),
            score: data.find(d => d.rank == x).item.score
        }
    }
})

console.log(result)
```

O segredo para agregar os dados do `userName` num array é quebrar a lógica em duas partes.

Primeiro você filtra o array original pelo rank usando `data.filter(d => d.rank == x)` que retorna um array com todos os itens de um determinado rank.

Agora de posse desse array, basta selecionar os `userNames` e agregá-los num novo array usando o método `map( u => u.item.userName)`.

Caso o trecho `[...new Set(data.map(x => x.rank))]` pareça confuso, sugiro dar uma olhada na [documentação do object Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: Vou tentar seguir alógica e depois posto o resultado aqui.

Comment: E aí, conseguiu?

Comment: Sim cara, segui o seu exemplo, agora estou estudando sobre websocket pra atualizar esse ranking em tempo real.

Comment: Show!
Qualquer coisa dúvida, posta aí.
Você poderia marcar esta resposta como a correta, então?

Comment: Obrigado por avisar, agora que vi que tem um simbolo para tornar a resposta correta.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui implementar um código para resolver o problema, mas nem de perto é o mais otimizado e sucinto (na minha opinião).

Mas pelo menos você percorre o seu array apenas duas vezes, uma no `map` e outra no `filter`.

E uma observação importante: o array **precisa estar ordenado pelo rank**!

```js
let array = [ 
  { rank: 1, item: { userName: 'Rafaela', score: 600 } },
  { rank: 2, item: { userName: 'Carla', score: 410 } },
  { rank: 2, item: { userName: 'Yuri', score: 410 } },
  { rank: 3, item: { userName: 'Jompas', score: 300 } },
  { rank: 4, item: { userName: 'Jonas', score: 266 } },
  { rank: 4, item: { userName: 'Tereza', score: 266 } },
]

let arrayMapeado = array.map((valor, index, elements) => {
  let proximo = elements[index + 1]; // pega o proximo valor da iteração, elements é o array passado no map
  let atual = valor;
  
  if(!proximo) {
    return false; // gera um entrada false, que iremos tratar depois
  }
  
  // Verifica se há scores iguais
  if(atual.item.score === proximo.item.score) {
    let usernameAtual = atual.item.userName;
    let usernameProximo = proximo.item.userName;
    usernameAtual = [usernameAtual, usernameProximo]; // monta o username
    valor.item.userName = usernameAtual;
    elements.splice(index, 1); // Remove o elemento duplicado
    return valor;
  }
  valor.item.userName = [valor.item.userName] // tranforsma o userName em array, caso não tenha entrado no if
  return valor;
});

let arrayNormalizado = arrayMapeado.filter(item => item !== false) // retira o false

console.log(arrayNormalizado);
```

Comment: Quase resolve o meu problema, só nãp resolveu pq esse script excluí um item do array. De qualquer modo já é um bom começo, irei verificar o código e tentar fazer uma melhoria. Obrigado.

Comment: Qual parte você diz que ele exclui? Só pra eu poder complementar a resposta.

Comment: O ultimo ou o primeiro, sei que falta 1 objeto. Mas segui outro método e resolvi o meu problema